# VS 2010 Intellisense mess while trying to type lambda expression in EF 4.0 query

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Short time ago I came into a strange situation .

Here the code I want to write first:

```
context.Customers.Where(c => c.Name == customerName);
```

In VS2010 I can't finish this line, at the moment of typing the lambda expression.

```
context.Customers.Where(c
```

changes to IDE suggestion

```
context.Customers.Where(customer
```

Finally I wrote it after deleting it manually and code within brackets are underlined red.

*"C#: Unknown Method 'Where(?)' of 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet*

First time I see this. Is this an IDE bug? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: After pressing c, you can press escape that will stop auto complete. I have finally developed a habit that I will press escape when I want to type lambda expression.

Comment: The escape suggestion works, but still the Unknown Method error appears.

Comment: Make sure you have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Thanks. It was placed in the wrong nested namespace.